# Setting up Google Analytics Trackers

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up Google Analytics v2 for my Android app.

Right now, I'm trying to track the different screens by setting up trackers for my Activities and Fragments. I have two Activities that everything inherits from and one Fragment that everything inherits from and I would like to just put the tracking code in those three classes so I don't have to go through and put tracking code in every single class.

```
 @Override
  public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      EasyTracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance();
      tracker.setContext(getActivity());
      String title = getTitle();
      EasyTracker.getTracker().sendView(title);
  }
```

First, with my Fragment class, I keep getting an error on my sendView(title) line. I would like to pass the name of the actual Fragment class that inherited this instead of a lame string like "Fragment" (which seems to be the only thing that's working for me...)

In my Activities I have:

```
  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      EasyTracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance();
      tracker.setContext(this);
      tracker.activityStart(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
  }
```

Is this the proper way to do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated Google Analytics successfully in my App using Easytracker:

```
 @Override
  protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      EasyTracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance();
      tracker.setContext(this);
      tracker.activityStart(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
  }
```

I use this code only in my Main Activity

For other Activities and Fragmants:

I use:

```
  EasyTracker.getTracker().sendView(title);
```

Just in place of Title I send the relevant Screen View Names that I need to track.

It works just fine for me.

Comment: What should i do for v3 ?

Comment: Check this for details https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration